# Computer Freezes Upon Launching GPU Related Application

Tags: windows-7, crash, gpu, gaming, crossfire

I just installed a second GPU to crossfire. When I run any application that requires the use of my GPU (ie - 3dMark, or games), my computer would freeze immediately upon launching the application. There is no error screen, or audio cues. The mouse cursor would also be locked in place. I have looked through my C/Windows/Minidump for a log file, but none has been created for this event. Upon forcing to restart my computer, DOS says that it has recovered from an error and presents me with options to reboot into safe mode.

This is the first time I am crossfiring. I have been using a single GPU for over a year without any problems. I just installed my second GPU this morning, so I presume it is because of this new hardware change. I have done the following:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled my drivers (running Catalyst 13.9)
2. Removed my GPU from the motherboard, and plugged it back in.
3. Switched the crossfire bridge on the GPUs

My specs:

- i5-3570K at stock 3.5GHz
- XFX 7970 at stock 925GHz
- PowerColor 7970 at stock 925GHz (just bought)
- AsRock Z77 Extreme4
- 16GB DDR3
- Corsair TX750
- Windows 7

Comment: How powerful is your power supply?  In my experience, that is the most likely culprit - your power supply not being able to feed both GPUs.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm using a Corsair TX750. 750 watts should be more the enough.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my new GPU is faulty. The proper procedure in this case would be to check each card individually before attempting to CrossFire.